# net 6 load assemblies at runtim to AppDomain.CurrentDomain

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-6.0, .net-4.6

The goal is to migrate a .net 4.6 FullFramework lib to .netStandard /.net6. There is one app that is using a typegrabber, so it is looking in its executing folder for *.dll and tries to load them into AppDomain.CurrentDomain (no comments if this is good or bad but it has to be done like this). The dlls that should be loaded are .netStandard 2.1

But the .net 6 app is throwing errors like this:

### "Could not load file or assembly 'Framework.Tests.NetCore, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, processorArchitecture=MSIL'. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden."

The Code looks like this:

```
        public virtual AppDomain App
        {
            get
            {
                return AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            }
        }

    private void LoadMatchingAssemblies(string directoryPath)
    {
          foreach (var dllPath in Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.dll"))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var an = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(dllPath);
                            if (this.Matches(an.FullName) && !loadedAssemblyNames.Contains(an.FullName))
                            {
                              this.App.Load(an);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (BadImageFormatException)
                        {
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            string es = e.Message;
                        }
                    }
     }
```

Comment: What framework is the dll targetting that you're trying to load?

Comment: .netStandard 2.1

Comment: Is there a difference if you just use `Assembly.Load()` or `Assembly.LoadFrom()`? .NET 6.0 doesn't support appdomains anymore (the class does basically nothing), so your comment about requiring loading to the CurrentDomain is pointless.

Comment: at the moment it is the same class as it was in .net 4.6 but in a .netStandard Project. My question is what is replacing the functionality of AppDomain.CurrentDomain and how i can rewrite it, without changing all logic of my other functions.

Comment: What other features do you have that depend on AppDomain? The implementation in .NET 6.0 is just a placeholder, so ideally, you just remove all references to it.